# Binding a string with value in Angular 2

Tags: angular

How to concatenate string with a value as we do in JAVA  "The total pay is " + totalPay.

I want to do it in Angular 2+ like 'Hi Hello" +req.body.hello

Comment: Have you read the basic introductory tutorial on Angular? How can you develop any app without this knowledge? It's literally the most basic thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it inside the component.ts

it should be

```
let result = 'Hi Hello" +req.body.hello;
```

if you want to do it in HTML, do the above and

```
{{result}}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is the best way (AFAIK) to concatenate a string and a variable together.

```
let concString = `This is my ${name}`;
```

In Angular template

```
<tag>This is my {{name}}</tag>
```

Comment: Why concatenate strings in templates when it's already one large string? `This is my {{ name }}` is way more common.